# Clients-Server chat with AES encryption in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to make a chat program in Java with encrypted messages(you can send encrypted message and when you receive message you have to 
decrypt it). I found this code for decryption and encryption:

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class test {
private static String algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static byte[] keyValue=new byte[]      {'0','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1','2','3','4','5','6','7'};// your key

// Performs Encryption
public static String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception
{
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher chiper = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        chiper.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = chiper.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
}

// Performs decryption
public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception
{
        // generate key
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher chiper = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        chiper.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedText);
        byte[] decValue = chiper.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
}

//generateKey() is used to generate a secret key for AES algorithm
private static Key generateKey() throws Exception
{
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, algorithm);
        return key;
}
```

So the encryption function works well:

```
public void send(String text) {
    try {
        test test = new test();
        String textTS = chat.AES.test.encrypt(text);
        OUT.println(ClientGUI.UserName + ": " + textTS);
        OUT.flush();
        Client_GUI.TF_Message.setText("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I can't really receive message, I think the problem is in key generation, I never save key which I used to encrypt message and trying to decrypt it with new key, but if the problem in that how can I send the key?
The code for receive function:

```
public void receive() {
    try {
        if (INPUT.hasNext()) {
            String MESSAGE = INPUT.nextLine();
            String dMessage = chat.AES.test.decrypt(MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(dMessage);
            if (MESSAGE.contains("#?!")) {
                String TEMP1 = MESSAGE.substring(3);
                TEMP1 = TEMP1.replace("[", "");
                TEMP1 = TEMP1.replace("]", "");

                String[] CurrentUsers = TEMP1.split(", ");

                Client_GUI.JL_ONLINE.setListData(CurrentUsers);
            } else {
                Client_GUI.TA_CONVERSATION.append(MESSAGE + "\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sending the key along with the ciphertext won't give you any security, but only some obfuscation. Either you let users type in a password and derive the key from that or you need to distribute the key with through asymmetric encryption like RSA.

Comment: Using just CBC without key management or integrity/authenticity is completely useless for a transport protocol. You need to have at least an inkling of an idea what you are actually doing instead of just grab and run.